# Data clustering in KMeans Algorithm using binary tree structure

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I am having trouble in generating code for KMeans clustering in java. I have already known the algorithm but it's very hard to write in in java code.
My assignment is to retrieve data from database then run the Clustering with KMeans, in this case, the data first have to be formed in Recursive binary tree structure.
the scenario is

1. first create parent node, if parent is NULL then set the global_iteration = 0
2. creating node and its relation to parent
3. retreive all data from database (i use JDBC) to parents (next we call it dataset)
4. if dataset < outlierSize, mark this node as outlier (outlierSize is stated by programmer) then STOP.
5. if dataset < maxIteration (stated by programmers) then STOP
6. compute centroid from dataset (in this case is 2 cause we build binary tree)
7. Cal KMeans  class
8. global_iteration++
9. for each dataset: continue recursing.

then we have to make a class KMeans that will be called to be inserted to the node.

KMeans(dataset,k,maxIteration,minChange)

remark: k=number of cluster,minChange: the value during the centroid change to be parameter that whether clustering should be still processed or not. Kmeans clustering is just the same with the commong KMeans algorithm.

Thank you so much for helping me doing this assignment :)

Comment: If this is a homework question, please tag as such. Otherwise, perhaps you don't want to reinvent the wheel and take something readily available from the interweb.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) source [code for K-Means](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Science/weka/weka/clusterers/SimpleKMeans.java.htm), may be it will help you to approach the problem.

Comment: still no idea, could anybody please give me the example? i am newbie in java

Comment: This is not a homework solving site. Try it by yourself and ask questions regarding some stuff you already made...

Answer (score 0):

```
You can implement k-means algorithm as:
SimpleKMeans kmeans = new SimpleKMeans();

kmeans.setSeed(10);

// This is the important parameter to set
kmeans.setPreserveInstancesOrder(true);
kmeans.setNumClusters(numberOfClusters);
kmeans.buildClusterer(instances);

// This array returns the cluster number (starting with 0) for each instance
// The array has as many elements as the number of instances
int[] assignments = kmeans.getAssignments();

int i=0;
for(int clusterNum : assignments) {
System.out.printf("Instance %d -> Cluster %d", i, clusterNum);
i++;
}
```

Comment: He probably doesn't want to use Weka k-means, but implement the *more efficient* variant of k-means that exploits the binary tree structure. But anyway, this question is two years old. Guess his "assignment" is already over.